# is it possible to extend Service class and not declare as service component in manifest file in android

Tags: android

Currently I am learning Android by studying source code of K9 mail app. what i couldn't understand is that the CoreService class (https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/blob/master/src/com/fsck/k9/service/CoreService.java) extends Service but it has not been declared as service component in manifest file (https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml). could somebody clarify this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, he defined this service to put in it shared staff between many services. then his services are heritating from this service.
You can do it as well with your activities , you creat one Activity that contains reapeted staff , and then all your activities will heritate from it. 
but, if you want to lunch this service and not one of its subclasses (the services that are implementing it), this service will not be able to lunch because the Runtime will not be able to find it (because it is not present in the manifest).